# non opacity element on opacity element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i tried to design a button inside some div.
the div has an opacity of 0.8, but i don't want its button (child-button) to have its super (ancestor) div opacity. how can this be achived?
i have tried this **html**:

```
 <div class="divBox">
      <span class="title"> Some title </span>
      <hr>

      <div>
           <span> Some Content </span>
      </div>

      <div class="divButton">
           <a class="myButton"> Button </a>
      </div>
 </div>
```

**the css:**

```
.divBox{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
}

.divButton{
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    padding-top: 3%;
}

.myButton{
    background-color: #295b9f;
    color: white;
    padding: .5em .5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: aliceblue;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rgba(r, g, b, a)` `background-color` instead of `opacity` for both the parent and the child. The `a` refers to the alpha value or opacity.

i.e.

```
.parent {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0, 0.8); /* change r,g,b as needed */
}

.parent .child {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0, 1); /* change r,g,b as needed */
}
```

Comment: Remove the `//` - They aren't valid CSS comments. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uLLA7/

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the HTML a bit and add opacity to this class "opacity-layer"

```
<div class="divBox">
  <div class="opacity-layer">
     <span class="title"> Some title </span>
     <hr>

      <div>
       <span> Some Content </span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divButton">
       <a class="myButton"> Button </a>
  </div>
```